# Javascript how to replace string with RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, match

I have this string

```
"red col.  yellow;   col.  black;  col.  green; orange; col. white; blue col. purple;"
```

and I need to get yellow, black,green, white,purple colors, just colors without 'col.' and  ';' and change this string to this:

```
 "red col. < a>yellow<\a> ; col. < a>black<\a> ; col. < a>green<\a>; orange; col. <a>white<\a>; blue; col. < a>purple<\a>;"
```

how can I make it with javascript reg exp, please help

Answer (score 4):

use `/\w+(?=;)/g` to match the words ending with `;` and [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace the match with what you want :

```js
const str = 'red col.  yellow;   col.  black;  col.  green; orange; col. white; blue col. purple;';

const result = str.replace(/\w+(?=;)/g, match => '<a>' + match + '</a>');

console.log(result);
```

for specific colors :

```js
const str = 'red col.  yellow;   col.  black;  col.  green; orange; col. white; blue col. purple;';

const colors = ["yellow", "black", "green", "white", "purple"];

const exp = new RegExp(colors.join('|'), 'g');

const result = str.replace(exp, match => '<a>' + match + '</a>');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: This adds an anchor for `orange` as well

Answer (score 0):

You could use a capturing group to [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Switching_words_in_a_string) like this: (Not sure of this is the most efficient way)

```js
const str = "red col.  yellow;   col.  black;  col.  green; orange; col. white; blue col. purple;"

const newStr = str.replace(/(?<=col.)(\s+)(\w+);/g, "$1<a>$2</a>;")

console.log(newStr)
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#Deprecated_features

Comment: @Taki only the static `RegExp.$1` properties are deprecated. `$1`-`$9` can still be used in the `replace` method. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53425276/3082296